# InvocationTargetException while switching scenes with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, controller, scenebuilder, invocationtargetexception

I'm working with JavaFX and use .fxml files and associated controller classes, to move from scene to scene and have functionalities for buttons etc.

My MainMenuController is concerned with the menus of a game I am developing. The MainController is concerned with the gameboard which I am trying to load. But whenever I press the "Launch Game" button, I get those errors:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/.../bin/client/ui/Main.fxml

cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
where: 
/C:/.../bin/client/ui/Main.fxml

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaenter code herefx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 49 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Unknown Source)
at client.ui.MainMenuController.handleButtonAction(MainMenuController.java:251)
... 58 more
```

To me it seems like that the MainController is causing the problem and 
therefore preventing Main.fxml to load.

Here is the method of MainMenuController where "launchGame" should switch to a new scene with Main.fxml as root (**last }else if(...){ instruction**):

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
Stage stage = null;
Parent root = null;
try {

  if (e.getSource() == leaveBrowserButton) {
    stage = (Stage) leaveBrowserButton.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PlayGameSelection.fxml"));
  }
  if (e.getSource() == connect1Button) {
    stage = (Stage) connect1Button.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Lobby.fxml"));
    StartUI.getClient().connect(0);
  }
  if (e.getSource() == connect2Button) {
    StartUI.getClient().connect(1);
  }
  if (e.getSource() == connect3Button) {
    StartUI.getClient().connect(2);
  }
  if (e.getSource() == playGame) {
    stage = (Stage) playGame.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PlayGameSelection.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == login) {
    stage = (Stage) login.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == createProfile) {
    stage = (Stage) createProfile.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CreateNewPlayer.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == goToMainMenu) {
    stage = (Stage) goToMainMenu.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == goToCreateNewPlayer) {
    stage = (Stage) goToCreateNewPlayer.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CreateNewPlayer.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == backToLogin) {
    stage = (Stage) backToLogin.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == manageProfile) {
    stage = (Stage) manageProfile.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ManagePlayer.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == backToGame) {
    stage = (Stage) backToGame.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == backToMain || e.getSource() == goBackButton) {
    stage = (Stage) backToMain.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == playLocalGame) {
    stage = (Stage) playLocalGame.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Browser.fxml"));
  } else if (e.getSource() == launchGame) {
    stage = (Stage) launchGame.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    StartGameMessage startGame =
        new StartGameMessage(StartUI.getClient().getGamestate().whosTurnIsIt(), false, 0);
    StartUI.getClient().addMessage(startGame);
  } else {
    stage = (Stage) playGame.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(e.getClass().getName()));
  }
} catch (Exception e1) {
  System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
  System.out.println(e1);
  System.out.println("cause: " + e1.getCause());
  System.out.println("where: " + e1.getLocalizedMessage());
  System.out.println(e1.getStackTrace());
}

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}
```

I set the controller to MainController in the Main.fxml file so I don't see a problem there:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="client.ui.MainController">
```

And here my MainController:

```
package client.ui;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import client.domain.DevelopmentCard;
import client.domain.NobleTile;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.Glow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import networkcommunication.domain.ActionTakeThreeTokens;
import networkcommunication.domain.ActionTakeTwoTokens;
import server.application.GameController;

public class MainController implements Initializable, Repaintable {

  @FXML
  protected ImageView top1;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView top2;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView top3;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView top4;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView center1;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView center2;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView center3;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView center4;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView bottom1;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView bottom2;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView bottom3;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView bottom4;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView tokenRed7;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView tokenBlack7;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView tokenBlue7;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView tokenYellow5;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView tokenGreen7;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView tokenWhite7;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView noble1;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView noble2;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView noble3;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView noble4;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView noble5;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView reserve1;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView reserve2;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView reserve3;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView buy1;
  @FXML
  protected AnchorPane anchorPane;

  @FXML
  protected ImageView currentPosition;

  @FXML
  protected VBox buyBox;
  @FXML
  protected Button reserve;
  @FXML
  protected Button buy;
  @FXML
  protected Button goToGameMenu;
  @FXML
  protected Button playGame;
  @FXML
  protected Button playLocalGame;
  @FXML
  protected Button backToMain;
  @FXML
  protected Text counterGameYellowToken;
  @FXML
  protected Label yellowGameLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label blackGameLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label blueGameLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label greenGameLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label whiteGameLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label redGameLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label yellowOwnLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label blackOwnLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label blueOwnLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label greenOwnLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label whiteOwnLabel;
  @FXML
  protected Label redOwnLabel;
  @FXML
  protected CheckBox checkBox;
  @FXML
  protected ColorAdjust colorConstant = new ColorAdjust();
  @FXML
  protected ImageView optionPreviewCard;
  @FXML
  protected HBox buyHbox;

  private int[] counter;
  private int[] saveInt = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  private int[] saveForThree = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  private int[] saveSpecificTokens = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  private int[] previousCounter = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  private Image forReserve;
  protected List<ImageView> devCardsLevelO;
  protected List<ImageView> devCardsLevelOO;
  protected List<ImageView> devCardsLevelOOO;
  protected List<ImageView> yellowTokens;
  protected List<ImageView> blackTokens;
  protected List<ImageView> redTokens;
  protected List<ImageView> blueTokens;
  protected List<ImageView> greenTokens;
  protected List<ImageView> whiteTokens;
  protected List<ImageView> nobleTilesImgV;
  protected List<DevelopmentCard> devCards1;
  protected List<DevelopmentCard> devCards2;
  protected List<DevelopmentCard> devCards3;
  protected List<NobleTile> nobleTiles;
  private List<Label> pressableTokens = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<Label> ownTokens = new ArrayList<>();
  @FXML
  protected Label player2view;
  @FXML
  protected SplitPane enemySplitPane;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView enemyReserve1;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView enemyReserve2;
  @FXML
  protected ImageView enemyReserve3;
  @FXML
  protected HBox enemyReserveBox;

  @FXML
  public void changeTokenCount(MouseEvent e) throws IOException {
    pressableTokens.addAll(
        Arrays.asList(blackGameLabel, whiteGameLabel, redGameLabel, greenGameLabel, blueGameLabel));
    ownTokens.addAll(
        Arrays.asList(blackOwnLabel, whiteOwnLabel, redOwnLabel, greenOwnLabel, blueOwnLabel));
    for (int cycle = 0; cycle < pressableTokens.size(); cycle++) {
      if (e.getSource() == pressableTokens.get(cycle) && counter[cycle] < 2) {

        previousCounter = counter.clone();
        counter[cycle]++;
        pressableTokens.get(cycle).setText("x" + Integer.toString(5 - counter[cycle]));
        ownTokens.get(cycle).setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[cycle]));
        if (counter[cycle] == 2 && lastEntryPosition() == cycle) {
          System.out.println("I just pressed x" + pressableTokens.get(cycle).getId() + " twice!");
        }
        if (counter[cycle] == 2) {
          pressableTokens.get(cycle).setDisable(true);
        }
        if (tookThreeDifferentTokens()) {
          System.out.println("I just took three tokens");
          ActionTakeThreeTokens tookThree = new ActionTakeThreeTokens(
              StartUI.getClient().getGamestate().whosTurnIsIt(), saveSpecificTokens);
          StartUI.getClient().addMessage(tookThree);
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(saveSpecificTokens));
          saveSpecificTokens = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        }
        System.out.println("I just pressed: " + pressableTokens.get(cycle).getId());
        break;
      }
    }

    for (

        int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      setBrightness(devCardsLevelO.get(i), -0.2);
      setBrightness(devCardsLevelOO.get(i), -0.2);
      setBrightness(devCardsLevelOOO.get(i), -0.2);
      colorConstant.setBrightness(-0.2);

      if (devCards1.get(i).getPriceDiamond() <= counter[2]
          && devCards1.get(i).getPriceEmerald() <= counter[4]
          && devCards1.get(i).getPriceSapphire() <= counter[5]
          && devCards1.get(i).getPriceRuby() <= counter[3]
          && devCards1.get(i).getPriceOnyx() <= counter[1]) {
        setBrightness(devCardsLevelO.get(i), 0.35);
      }
      if (devCards2.get(i).getPriceDiamond() <= counter[2]
          && devCards2.get(i).getPriceEmerald() <= counter[4]
          && devCards2.get(i).getPriceSapphire() <= counter[5]
          && devCards2.get(i).getPriceRuby() <= counter[3]
          && devCards2.get(i).getPriceOnyx() <= counter[1]) {
        setBrightness(devCardsLevelOO.get(i), 0.35);
      }
      if (devCards3.get(i).getPriceDiamond() <= counter[2]
          && devCards3.get(i).getPriceEmerald() <= counter[4]
          && devCards3.get(i).getPriceSapphire() <= counter[5]
          && devCards3.get(i).getPriceRuby() <= counter[3]
          && devCards3.get(i).getPriceOnyx() <= counter[1]) {
        setBrightness(devCardsLevelOOO.get(i), 0.35);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("counter: " + Arrays.toString(counter) + "\tpreviousCounter: "
        + Arrays.toString(previousCounter) + "\tsaveThree: " + Arrays.toString(saveForThree)
        + "\tYou took those different tokens: " + Arrays.toString(saveSpecificTokens));
    System.out.println("");
  }

  @FXML
  public void manageCardClick(MouseEvent e) throws IOException {
    if (e.getSource() == reserve) {
      setReserveImage(forReserve);
      buyBox.setVisible(false);
      counter[0]++;
      yellowGameLabel.setText("x" + Integer.toString(4 - counter[0]));
      yellowOwnLabel.setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[0]));
    } else if (e.getSource() == buy) {
      setBuyImage(forReserve);
      buyBox.setVisible(false);
      blackGameLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(5 - counter[1] + devCards1.get(1).getPriceOnyx()));
      blackOwnLabel.setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[1] - devCards1.get(1).getPriceOnyx()));
      redGameLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(5 - counter[3] + devCards1.get(1).getPriceRuby()));
      redOwnLabel.setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[3] - devCards1.get(1).getPriceRuby()));
      blueGameLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(5 - counter[5] + devCards1.get(1).getPriceSapphire()));
      blueOwnLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[5] - devCards1.get(1).getPriceSapphire()));
      greenGameLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(5 - counter[4] + devCards1.get(1).getPriceEmerald()));
      greenOwnLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[4] - devCards1.get(1).getPriceEmerald()));
      whiteGameLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(5 - counter[2] + devCards1.get(1).getPriceDiamond()));
      whiteOwnLabel
          .setText("x" + Integer.toString(counter[2] + devCards1.get(1).getPriceDiamond()));
    }
  }

  private int lastEntryPosition() {
    int out = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
      if (counter[i] - previousCounter[i] != 0) {
        out = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Position: " + out);
    return out;
  }

  private boolean tookThreeDifferentTokens() {
    int countToThree = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
      if (counter[i] - saveForThree[i] != 0) {
        countToThree++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(countToThree);
    if (countToThree == 3) {
      for (int j = 0; j < counter.length; j++) {
        saveSpecificTokens[j] = counter[j] - saveForThree[j];
      }
      saveForThree = counter.clone();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @FXML
  protected void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
    Stage stage;

    Parent root;

    if (e.getSource() == goToGameMenu) {
      stage = (Stage) goToGameMenu.getScene().getWindow();
      root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GameMenu.fxml"));
    } else {
      stage = (Stage) playGame.getScene().getWindow();
      root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

  }

  public void hideImgView(ImageView imgV) {
    imgV.setVisible(false);
  }

  public void selectDevCard(ImageView imgV) {
    if (imgV.getScaleX() == 1.0) {
      imgV.setEffect(new Glow(0.7));
      imgV.setScaleX(1.15);
      imgV.setScaleY(1.15);
    } else {
      DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();
      imgV.setEffect(shadow);
      imgV.setScaleX(1.0);
      imgV.setScaleY(1.0);
    }
  }

  public void setReserveImage(Image im) throws IOException {
    if (reserve1.getImage() == null) {
      reserve1.setImage(im);
      setNewCard();
    } else if (reserve2.getImage() == null) {
      reserve2.setImage(im);
      setNewCard();
    } else if (reserve3.getImage() == null) {
      reserve3.setImage(im);
      setNewCard();

    } else {
      Stage warning = new Stage();
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Warning.fxml"));
      Scene warningScene = new Scene(root);
      warning.setScene(warningScene);
      warning.show();
      PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
      delay.setOnFinished(e -> warning.close());
      delay.play();
    }

  }

  public void setBuyImage(Image im) {
    ImageView buyView = new ImageView(optionPreviewCard.getImage());
    buyView.fitHeightProperty().bind(buyHbox.heightProperty());
    buyView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    buyHbox.getChildren().add(buyView);
    setNewCard();
  }

  public void setImageEffect(ImageView imageView, double brightness) {
    ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
    colorAdjust.setBrightness(brightness);
    imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust));
    imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> imageView.setEffect(colorConstant));
  }

  public void setBrightness(ImageView imageView, double brightness) {
    ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
    colorAdjust.setBrightness(brightness);
    imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust);
  }

  private void setNewCard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (devCardsLevelO.get(i).getImage() == null) {
        devCardsLevelO.get(i)
            .setImage(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(devCards1.get(4).getPath())));
      }
      if (devCardsLevelOO.get(i).getImage() == null) {
        devCardsLevelOO.get(i)
            .setImage(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(devCards2.get(4).getPath())));
      }
      if (devCardsLevelOOO.get(i).getImage() == null) {
        devCardsLevelOOO.get(i)
            .setImage(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(devCards3.get(4).getPath())));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    StartUI.getRepaintThread().addInterface(this);
    this.counter = new int[6];
    this.saveInt = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.counter.length; i++) {
      this.counter[i] = 0;
      this.saveInt[i] = 0;
    }

    this.devCardsLevelO = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.devCardsLevelOO = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.devCardsLevelOOO = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.yellowTokens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.blackTokens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    redTokens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.blueTokens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.greenTokens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.whiteTokens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    this.nobleTilesImgV = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    this.devCards1 = new ArrayList<DevelopmentCard>();
    this.devCards2 = new ArrayList<DevelopmentCard>();
    this.devCards3 = new ArrayList<DevelopmentCard>();
    this.nobleTiles = new ArrayList<NobleTile>();

    this.devCardsLevelO.addAll(Arrays.asList(bottom1, bottom2, bottom3, bottom4));
    this.devCardsLevelOO.addAll(Arrays.asList(center1, center2, center3, center4));
    this.devCardsLevelOOO.addAll(Arrays.asList(top1, top2, top3, top4));
    this.nobleTilesImgV.addAll(Arrays.asList(noble1, noble2, noble3, noble4, noble5));


    for (int i = 0; i < devCardsLevelO.size(); i++) {
      int k = i;
      setImageEffect(devCardsLevelO.get(k), 0.2);

      devCardsLevelO.get(i).setSmooth(true);
      devCardsLevelO.get(i).setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        forReserve = devCardsLevelO.get(k).getImage();
        optionPreviewCard.setImage(forReserve);
        buyBox.setVisible(true);
        devCards1.get(k).setSelectable(false);
        devCardsLevelO.get(k).setImage(null);
      });

      setImageEffect(devCardsLevelOO.get(k), 0.2);
      devCardsLevelOO.get(k).setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        buyBox.setVisible(true);
        forReserve = devCardsLevelOO.get(k).getImage();
        optionPreviewCard.setImage(forReserve);
        devCards2.get(k).setSelectable(false);
        devCardsLevelOO.get(k).setImage(null);
      });

      setImageEffect(devCardsLevelOOO.get(k), 0.2);
      devCardsLevelOOO.get(k).setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        buyBox.setVisible(true);
        forReserve = devCardsLevelOOO.get(k).getImage();
        optionPreviewCard.setImage(forReserve);
        devCards3.get(k).setSelectable(false);
        devCardsLevelOOO.get(k).setImage(null);
      });
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void update() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        devCards1 = StartUI.getClient().getGamestate().getDevelopmentCardsLevelO();
        devCards2 = StartUI.getClient().getGamestate().getDevelopmentCardsLevelOO();
        devCards3 = StartUI.getClient().getGamestate().getDevelopmentCardsLevelOOO();
        nobleTiles = StartUI.getClient().getGamestate().getNobleTiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < nobleTilesImgV.size(); i++) {
          if (nobleTiles.get(i).isSelectable()) {
            nobleTilesImgV.get(i).setImage(
                new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(nobleTiles.get(i).getPath())));
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < devCardsLevelO.size(); i++) {
          if (devCards1.get(i).isSelectable()) {
            devCardsLevelO.get(i).setImage(
                new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(devCards1.get(i).getPath())));
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < devCardsLevelOO.size(); i++) {
          if (devCards2.get(i).isSelectable()) {
            devCardsLevelOO.get(i).setImage(
                new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(devCards2.get(i).getPath())));
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < devCardsLevelOOO.size(); i++) {
          if (devCards3.get(i).isSelectable()) {
            devCardsLevelOOO.get(i).setImage(
                new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(devCards3.get(i).getPath())));
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I worked the hole day on it and still couldn't figure out what is causing this error. It starts to get very frustrating and it would be awesome if we could fix this :)

Comment: The first error tells you that the issue happens while trying to load `Main.fxml`. Since the load fails, you have a null root, and the exception you have posted indicates that the scene failed to load a null root. Can you add `e1.printStackTrace()` to the catch clause `catch (Exception e1) {}`, run it again and post the exception?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Wow! I could actually fix the issue with e1.printStackTrace() because it gave me an additional error and the exact line to the issue. I didn't saw that with System.out.print(e1.getStackTrace()). Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

from reading your StackTrace I see the following line: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null`.
That means you can't set the Root to be null.
In one of your snippets you have the following lines:

`@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
Stage stage = null;
Parent root = null;`

You are assigning you `Parent` to have a null value, that cause the `NullPointException` you are getting. I suggest you remove the `null` value you're assigning to the `Parent`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! It is that root stays null. But those lines are needed to initialize stage and root. The problem is, that root should be assigned with FXMLLoader.load(...). This works with every other scene I want to switch to except with Main.fxml.

Comment: FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")); returns null but I don't understand why.